# Why is my browser opening a "Log in to localhost:XXXXX" dialog when I try to open external documentation from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

When I open an external documentation for a class from Android Studio (Shift+F1), the result returned is below:

Browser is: Safari Version 15.5 (17613.2.7.1.8).
Android Studio version: Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526,

[image]

Comment: Do you use any proxy or antivirus software/firewall?

Comment: I have a third party AdBlock and a privacy report from Safari.

Answer (score 2):

I rarely use Intellij and haven't used Android Studio in while, however, from what I can find it seems to be an issue with Android Studio, which has not been fixed.

It appears that [Intellij comes with an in-built Web server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/php-built-in-web-server.html#ws_html_preview_output_built_in_browser), which is always running at `localhost:63342`.

Seems like same Web server is used by some Plugins like GitHub Plugin to process `OAuth2 authorizaion_code` login flow. In this flow user grants an authorization code to a third party client (GitHub Plugin) by logging into Resource Provider (GitHub site), which can then be used by client to get access to user resource (Git repository, profile etc.) Authorization code in this case is sent to callback URL hosted on in-built Web server `http://localhost:63342/api/github/oauth/authorization_code?code=SOME-RANDOM-STRING`

I got these details from following Jetbrains and Android studio issues

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257920
It has screenshots attached, with full authorization_code callback URL for GitHub Plugin.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176138642
This has a video attached of the same issue.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174787515

[image: Jetbrains issue for Intellij localhost login popup]

In all these issues, users will probably enter their GitHub credentials on the localhost login popup. However, in authorization_code flow, credentials are provided on the resource provider site (Github), where user is already logged in, and `localhost:63342...` callback is not supposed to show a login screen at all, its supposed to complete authorization code Oauth2 login flow and get an GitHub access token on behalf of the user. That's the issue these users are describing.

In your case you seem to be seeing this login popup when trying to see source code of some class. It's possible that the source code needed is not available locally and Intellij is trying to download it from GitHub. In doing so it mistakenly takes you through broken GitHub login flow. It's just a guess, you can probably get more insights if you inspect your browser's DevTools Network requests that are fired before `localhost:63342` page opens.

Here's another user describing exact same issue on Android studio site.
https://androidforums.com/threads/android-studio-documentation-localhost-63342.1321165/

GitHub Plugin issues seems to be still present in Android Studio, here are the last comments from issue

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176138642

[image: Comments on Android Studio issue]

**--UPDATE**

Here is the comment by Dmitry's in the JetBrains issue
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257920/Android-Studio-42-Beta-1-Github-integration-issue#focus=Comments-27-4680427.0-0

[image: Use token instead of OAuth]

Github Plugin indeed has a way to add account with Github personal access token. See the Intellij Github setting screenshot below

```
File > Settings > Version Control > Github > Add Accoount > Login In With Token
```

[image: Login with token in Github Plugin]

Here is the Github documentation on how to generate one.

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

You can also click on the `Generate` button on Github plugin's `Login In with Token` window, that'll take you directly to Github page to generate it.

[image: Generate button on Github Plugin]

It's possible that your issue may not be fixed even after adding Github account as it may not be related to Github but some other Plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying to open external doc for a class is not even showing the localhost browser now. Seems like the issue has history. There is a workaround mentioned, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257920/Android-Studio-42-Beta-1-Github-integration-issue#focus=Comments-27-4680427.0-0 but I don't understand it

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll work, but please see the updates in my post. I have added the steps for adding adding a Github account with a token in Github plugin.